# $(this + ":submit") does not work anymore in Jquery 1.8.1

Tags: jquery-selectors

In the past following worked perfectly:

```
$(this + ":submit").live('click', function (e) {

});
```

but I just started using JQuery 1.8.1 and I get following error on the selector `$(this + ":submit")`:

```
Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [object Object]:submit
```

'this' is a jquery select on the id of the form `$('form1')` and results in `[ form#form1 ]`

What could be an alternative syntax that works with Jquery 1.8.1 and previous versions of Jquery ?

Comment: It depends on what `this` refers to. You need to show a larger context.

Comment: @Esailija Well, theoretically `this` could refer to an object that has a `.toString()` method that returns a valid selector...

Comment: @Juhana the error shows `"[object Object]:submit"`

Comment: Right, that's why it would be nice to know what `this` actually is and what the OP assumes it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to supply `this` as context

```
$(":submit", this)
```

which is equivalent to

```
$(this).find(":submit")
```

I would suggest the latter since it makes things more readable.

---

**UPDATE**: Just to clarify, I'm editing in @Esailija's comment -

> This has never worked! - i.e.   $(this + ":submit")

Answer (score 0):

Either `this` is a submit button and you just need to call `$(this)`, or your submit button is somewhere in the `this` DOM tree and you should use `$(this).find(":submit")`